# How to synchronize the position tooltip of different line charts in d3js?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, d3.js, recharts

1. ***Goal:*** I'm using D3.js with ReactJS I want to hover over one chart and display a tooltip on all the other charts with their own data.
2. ***The actual result:*** The tooltip displays the data of the same hovered chart in all other charts.
3. ***Code:*** This is what I have tried [multiline-chart-tooltip-acoss-all-charts](https://m7vpce.csb.app/).
4. ***More details:*** In recharts there is a syncId props if two charts have the same syncId, these two charts can sync the position tooltip.I want to sync the position tooltip with D3JS.
5. ***The problem is in this file:*** ChartComponents/Tooltip.js.

```
const Tooltip = ({
    xScale,
    yScale,
    width,
    height,
    data,
    margin,
    anchorEl,
    children,
    currentIndex,
    tooltipColor,
    ...props
  }) => {
    const ref = useRef(null);
  
    const drawLine = useCallback(
      (x) => {
        d3.select(ref.current)
          .select(".tooltipLine")
          .attr("x1", x)
          .attr("x2", x)
          .attr("y1", -margin.top)
          .attr("y2", height);
      },
      [ref, height, margin]
    );
  
    const drawLineForOthers = useCallback(
      (x) => {
        d3.selectAll(".tooltip")
          .select(".tooltipLine")
          .attr("x1", x)
          .attr("x2", x)
          .attr("y1", -margin.top)
          .attr("y2", height);
      },
      [ref, height, margin]
    );
  
    const drawContent = useCallback(
      (x) => {
        const tz = Intl.DateTimeFormat().resolvedOptions().timeZone;
        // console.log('xScale.invert(x)', convertTZ(xScale.invert(x), tz));
        const tooltipContent = d3.select(ref.current).select(".tooltipContent");
        tooltipContent.attr("transform", (cur, i, nodes) => {
          const nodeWidth = nodes[i].getBoundingClientRect().width || 0;
          const translateX = nodeWidth + x > width ? x - nodeWidth - 12 : x + 8;
          return `translate(${translateX}, ${-margin.top})`;
        });
        tooltipContent
          .select(".contentTitle")
          .text("Le " + d3.timeFormat("%d %b %Y, %H:%M")(xScale.invert(x)));
        // .text(d3.timeFormat('%b %d, %Y %Z')(convertTZ(xScale.invert(x), tz)));
      },
      [xScale, margin, width]
    );
  
    const drawContentForOthers = useCallback(
      (x) => {
        // console.log('xScale.invert(x)', xScale.invert(x));
        const tooltipContentOthers = d3
          .selectAll(".tooltip")
          .select(".tooltipContent");
        tooltipContentOthers.attr("transform", (cur, i, nodes) => {
          const nodeWidth = nodes[i].getBoundingClientRect().width || 0;
          const translateX = nodeWidth + x > width ? x - nodeWidth - 12 : x + 8;
          return `translate(${translateX}, ${-margin.top})`;
        });
        tooltipContentOthers
          .select(".contentTitle")
          .text("Le " + d3.timeFormat("%d %b %Y, %H:%M")(xScale.invert(x)));
        // .text(d3.timeFormat('%b %d, %Y %H:%M')(xScale.invert(x)));
        // .text(
        //   d3.timeFormat('%b %d, %Y %H:%M')(convertTZ(xScale.invert(x) + '', tz))
        // );
      },
      [xScale, margin, width]
    );
  
    const drawBackground = useCallback(() => {
      // reset background size to defaults
      const contentBackground = d3
        .select(ref.current)
        .select(".contentBackground");
      contentBackground.attr("width", 125).attr("height", 20);
  
      // calculate new background size
      const tooltipContentElement = d3
        .select(ref.current)
        .select(".tooltipContent")
        .node();
      if (!tooltipContentElement) return;
  
      const contentSize = tooltipContentElement.getBoundingClientRect();
  
      contentBackground
        .attr("width", contentSize.width + 8)
        .attr(
          "height",
          contentSize.height > 80
            ? contentSize.height + 10
            : contentSize.height + 4
        );
    }, []);
  
    const drawBackgroundForOthers = useCallback(() => {
      // reset background size to defaults for others
      const contentBackgroundOthers = d3
        .selectAll(".tooltip")
        .select(".contentBackground")
        .filter((item, i) => currentIndex !== i);
      contentBackgroundOthers.attr("width", 125).attr("height", 40);
  
      // calculate new background size for others
      const tooltipContentElementOthers = d3
        .selectAll(".tooltip")
        .select(".tooltipContent")
        .node();
      if (!tooltipContentElementOthers) return;
  
      const contentSizeOthers = tooltipContentElementOthers.getBoundingClientRect();
      contentBackgroundOthers
        .attr("width", contentSizeOthers.width + 8)
        .attr(
          "height",
          contentSizeOthers.height > 80
            ? contentSizeOthers.height + 26
            : contentSizeOthers.height + 4
        );
    }, []);
  
    const onChangePosition = useCallback((d, i, isVisible) => {
      d3.select(ref.current)
        .selectAll(".performanceItemMarketValue")
        .filter((td, tIndex) => tIndex === i)
        .text(d && d.value && !isVisible ? "No data" : d && financial(d.value));
  
      const maxNameWidth = d3.max(
        d3.select(ref.current).selectAll(".performanceItemName").nodes(),
        (node) => node.getBoundingClientRect().width
      );
      d3.select(ref.current)
        .selectAll(".performanceItemValue")
        .attr(
          "transform",
          (datum, index, nodes) =>
            `translate(${
              nodes[index].previousSibling.getBoundingClientRect().width + 14
            },4)`
        );
  
      d3.select(ref.current)
        .selectAll(".performanceItemMarketValue")
        .attr("transform", `translate(${maxNameWidth + 60},4)`);
    }, []);
  
    const followPoints = useCallback(
      (e) => {
        const [x] = [e.layerX - margin.left];
        const xDate = xScale.invert(x);
        const bisectDate = d3.bisector((d) => d.date).left;
        let baseXPos = 0;
  
        drawCirclesOnLine();
        drawCirclesOnLineForOthers();
  
        drawLine(baseXPos);
        drawContent(baseXPos);
        drawBackground();
  
        drawLineForOthers(baseXPos);
        drawContentForOthers(baseXPos);
        drawBackgroundForOthers();
  
        function drawCirclesOnLine() {
          d3.select(ref.current)
            .selectAll(".tooltipLinePoint")
            .attr("transform", (cur, i) => {
              const index = bisectDate(data[i].items, xDate, 1);
              const d0 = data[i].items[index - 1];
              const d1 = data[i].items[index];
              let d;
              if (d1) d = xDate - d0.date > d1.date - xDate ? d1 : d0;
              if (d && d.date === undefined && d.value === undefined) {
                // move point out of container
                return "translate(-100,-100)";
              }
              const xPos = d && xScale(d.date) ? xScale(d.date) : 0;
              if (i === 0) {
                baseXPos = xPos;
              }
  
              let isVisible = true;
              if (xPos !== baseXPos) {
                isVisible = false;
              }
              const yPos = d && yScale(d.value) ? yScale(d.value) : 0;
  
              onChangePosition(d, i, isVisible);
  
              return isVisible
                ? `translate(${xPos}, ${yPos})`
                : "translate(-100,-100)";
            });
        }
  
        function drawCirclesOnLineForOthers() {
          d3.selectAll(".tooltip")
            .selectAll(".tooltipLinePoint")
            .attr("transform", (cur, i) => {
              const index = data[i] && bisectDate(data[i].items, xDate, 1);
              const d0 = data[i] && data[i].items[index - 1];
              const d1 = data[i] && data[i].items[index];
              let d = {};
              if (d1) d = xDate - d0.date > d1.date - xDate ? d1 : d0;
              if (d && d.date === undefined && d.value === undefined) {
                // move point out of container
                return "translate(-100,-100)";
              }
              const xPos = d && xScale(d.date) ? xScale(d.date) : 0;
              if (i === 0) {
                baseXPos = xPos;
              }
  
              let isVisible = true;
              if (xPos !== baseXPos) {
                isVisible = false;
              }
              const yPos = d && yScale(d.value) ? yScale(d.value) : 0;
  
              // onChangePositionForOthers(d, i, isVisible);
  
              return isVisible
                ? `translate(${xPos}, ${yPos})`
                : "translate(-100,-100)";
            });
        }
      },
      [
        // anchorEl,
        xScale,
        yScale,
        data,
        margin.left,
        drawLine,
        drawContent,
        drawBackground,
        onChangePosition,
        drawLineForOthers,
        drawContentForOthers,
        drawBackgroundForOthers
        // onChangePositionForOthers
      ]
    );
  
    useEffect(() => {
      d3.select(anchorEl)
        .on("mouseout.tooltip", () => {
          d3.select(ref.current).attr("opacity", 0);
          d3.selectAll(".tooltip").attr("opacity", 0);
        })
        .on("mouseover.tooltip", () => {
          d3.select(ref.current).attr("opacity", 1);
          d3.selectAll(".tooltip").attr("opacity", 1);
        })
        .on("mousemove.tooltip", (e) => {
          d3.select(ref.current)
            .selectAll(".tooltipLinePoint")
            .attr("opacity", 1);
          d3.selectAll(".tooltip")
            .selectAll(".tooltipLinePoint")
            .attr("opacity", 1);
          followPoints(e);
        });
    }, [anchorEl, followPoints]);
  
    if (!data.length) return null;
  
    return (
      <g ref={ref} opacity={0} {...props}>
        <line className="tooltipLine" />
        <g className="tooltipContent">
          <rect
            style={{ fill: tooltipColor }}
            className="contentBackground"
            rx={4}
            ry={4}
            opacity={0.4}
          />
          <text className="contentTitle" transform="translate(4,14)" />
          <g className="content" transform="translate(4,32)">
            {data.map(({ name, color }, i) => (
              <g key={name + "_" + i} transform={`translate(6,${22 * i})`}>
                <circle r={6} fill={color} />
                <text className="performanceItemName" transform="translate(10,4)">
                  {trimText(name, 14)}
                </text>
                <text className="performanceItemMarketValue" />
              </g>
            ))}
          </g>
        </g>
        {data.map(({ name, color }, index) => (
          <circle
            fill={color}
            className="tooltipLinePoint"
            r={6}
            key={name + "_" + index}
            opacity={0}
          />
        ))}
      </g>
    );
  };
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this is a year and a half late, but hopefully this can help someone else.

I solved this by letting the parent component manage the index of the data that should be displayed by the tooltip. Within each plot, there are two `useEffect`s. One renders the data, the other handles the tooltip rendering and interaction. Each tooltip element gets added by the svg and saved to a reference. In the second use effect, the reference is used to gain access to the elements that are needed to update the tooltip.

[Here's a codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/frosty-sea-c958xz?file=%2Fsrc%2FLiinePlot.js%3A10%2C19&layout=%257B%2522sidebarPanel%2522%253A%2522EXPLORER%2522%252C%2522rootPanelGroup%2522%253A%257B%2522direction%2522%253A%2522horizontal%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522UNKNOWN%2522%252C%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522ROOT_LAYOUT%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522UNKNOWN%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522vertical%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clqdwr54d00063b6l9b1q5mey%2522%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B70%252C30%255D%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522EDITOR%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522horizontal%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522EDITOR%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522EDITOR%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clqdwr54d00023b6lfjb2z8cw%2522%257D%255D%257D%252C%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522SHELLS%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522horizontal%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522SHELLS%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522SHELLS%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clqdwr54d00033b6lamc8v28c%2522%257D%255D%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B100%255D%257D%255D%257D%252C%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522DEVTOOLS%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522vertical%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522DEVTOOLS%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522DEVTOOLS%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clqdwr54d00053b6l0b7m1eik%2522%257D%255D%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B100%255D%257D%255D%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B48.31089207974539%252C51.68910792025461%255D%257D%252C%2522tabbedPanels%2522%253A%257B%2522clqdwr54d00023b6lfjb2z8cw%2522%253A%257B%2522id%2522%253A%2522clqdwr54d00023b6lfjb2z8cw%2522%252C%2522tabs%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522id%2522%253A%2522clqdxtgda00023b6ke2w92gmh%2522%252C%2522mode%2522%253A%2522permanent%2522%252C%2522type%2522%253A%2522FILE%2522%252C%2522initialSelections%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522startLineNumber%2522%253A2%252C%2522startColumn%2522%253A8%252C%2522endLineNumber%2522%253A2%252C%2522endColumn%2522%253A16%257D%255D%252C%2522filepath%2522%253A%2522%252Fsrc%252FApp.js%2522%252C%2522state%2522%253A%2522IDLE%2522%257D%255D%252C%2522activeTabId%2522%253A%2522clqdxtgda00023b6ke2w92gmh%2522%257D%252C%2522clqdwr54d00053b6l0b7m1eik%2522%253A%257B%2522tabs%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522id%2522%253A%2522clqdwr54d00043b6ljap5ljeu%2522%252C%2522mode%2522%253A%2522permanent%2522%252C%2522type%2522%253A%2522UNASSIGNED_PORT%2522%252C%2522port%2522%253A0%252C%2522path%2522%253A%2522%252F%2522%257D%255D%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clqdwr54d00053b6l0b7m1eik%2522%252C%2522activeTabId%2522%253A%2522clqdwr54d00043b6ljap5ljeu%2522%257D%252C%2522clqdwr54d00033b6lamc8v28c%2522%253A%257B%2522tabs%2522%253A%255B%255D%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clqdwr54d00033b6lamc8v28c%2522%257D%257D%252C%2522showDevtools%2522%253Atrue%252C%2522showShells%2522%253Atrue%252C%2522showSidebar%2522%253Atrue%252C%2522sidebarPanelSize%2522%253A15%257D)

In case that link fails, here's an App.js

```
import "./styles.css";
import LinePlot from "./LiinePlot";
import React, { useState } from "react";

const generateRandomData = () => {
  const numPoints = 20;
  const initialTime = 1;
  const timeIncrement = 1;

  const data = Array.from({ length: numPoints }, (_, index) => ({
    time: initialTime + index * timeIncrement,
    value: Math.random() * 10, // You can adjust the range of random values as needed
  }));

  return data;
};

const randomData1 = generateRandomData();
const randomData2 = generateRandomData();
const randomData3 = generateRandomData();

export default function App() {
  const [activeIndex, setActiveIndex] = useState(null);
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <LinePlot
        key={"first"}
        data={randomData1}
        label={"First"}
        units={"s"}
        activeIndex={activeIndex}
        setActiveIndex={setActiveIndex}
      />
      <LinePlot
        key={"first"}
        data={randomData2}
        label={"First"}
        units={"s"}
        activeIndex={activeIndex}
        setActiveIndex={setActiveIndex}
      />
      <LinePlot
        key={"first"}
        data={randomData3}
        label={"First"}
        units={"s"}
        activeIndex={activeIndex}
        setActiveIndex={setActiveIndex}
      />
    </div>
  );
}
```

and a line plot

```
import React, { useEffect, useRef } from "react";
import * as d3 from "d3";

const LinePlot = ({
  data,
  label,
  units,
  labelFontSize,
  tickFontSize,
  toolTipFontSize,
  height,
  precision,
  setActiveIndex,
  activeIndex,
}) => {
  const svgRef = useRef();
  const tooltipGroupRef = useRef();
  const verticalLineRef = useRef();
  const tooltipTextTimeRef = useRef();
  const tooltipTextValueRef = useRef();
  const dotRef = useRef();
  const xRef = useRef();
  const yRef = useRef();
  const width = height * 1.618; // golden ratio determins width based off of the height
  const marginTop = 30;
  const marginRight = 20;
  const marginBottom = 80;
  const marginLeft = width * 0.15;

  useEffect(() => {
    // x and y scales
    const x = d3
      .scaleLinear()
      .domain([0, 1.02 * d3.max(data, (d) => d.time)])
      .range([marginLeft, width - marginRight]);
    const y = d3
      .scaleLinear()
      .domain([
        0.98 * d3.min(data, (d) => d.value),
        1.02 * d3.max(data, (d) => d.value),
      ])
      .range([height - marginBottom, marginTop]);
    xRef.current = x;
    yRef.current = y;

    // Declare the line generator.
    const lineGenerator = d3
      .line()
      .x((d) => x(d.time))
      .y((d) => y(d.value));

    const svg = d3.select(svgRef.current);
    // remove old elements
    svg.selectAll("g").remove();
    svg.selectAll("path").remove();

    svg
      .attr("width", width)
      .attr("height", height)
      .attr("viewBox", [0, 0, width, height])
      .attr("style", "max-width: 100%; height: auto; height: intrinsic;")
      .style("background", "white")
      .style("border-radius", "8px")
      .style("box-shadow", "0px 0px 10px #c6c6c6")
      .style("pointer-events", "all");

    // Add the x-axis.
    svg
      .append("g")
      .attr("transform", `translate(0,${height - marginBottom})`)
      .style("font-size", `${tickFontSize}px`)
      .call(
        d3
          .axisBottom(x)
          .ticks(width / 80)
          .tickSizeOuter(0)
      )
      .call((g) =>
        g
          .append("text")
          .attr("x", width / 2)
          .attr("y", 2.5 * tickFontSize)
          .attr("fill", "currentColor")
          .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
          .style("font-size", `${labelFontSize}px`)
          .text(`time (s)`)
      );

    // Add the y-axis, remove the domain line, add grid lines and a label.
    svg
      .append("g")
      .attr("transform", `translate(${marginLeft},0)`)
      .style("font-size", `${tickFontSize}px`)
      .call(
        d3
          .axisLeft(y)
          .ticks(height / 40) // add grid lines
          .tickFormat((value) => value.toExponential(precision))
      )
      .call((g) => g.select(".domain").remove()) // remove the y axis spine
      .call((g) =>
        g
          .selectAll(".tick line") // set the tick color
          .attr("stroke-opacity", 0.1)
      )
      .call((g) =>
        g
          .selectAll(".tick line")
          .clone() // copy the ticks and stretch them to make horizontal grid lines
          .attr("x2", width - marginLeft - marginRight)
          .attr("stroke-opacity", 0.1)
      )
      .call((g) =>
        g
          .append("text")
          .attr("x", -marginLeft + 5)
          .attr("y", labelFontSize)
          .attr("fill", "currentColor")
          .attr("text-anchor", "start")
          .style("font-size", `${labelFontSize}px`)
          .text(`${label} (${units})`)
      );

    // Append a path for the line.
    svg
      .append("path")
      .attr("fill", "none")
      .attr("stroke", "steelblue")
      .attr("stroke-width", 1.5)
      .attr("d", lineGenerator(data));

    // Add the transparent vertical line.
    verticalLineRef.current = svg
      .append("line")
      .attr("class", "vertical-line")
      .style("stroke", "black")
      .style("stroke-width", "1px")
      .style("opacity", 0);

    tooltipGroupRef.current = svg
      .append("g")
      .style("opacity", 0)
      .attr("transform", `translate(5, ${height - 2 * toolTipFontSize})`);

    tooltipTextTimeRef.current = tooltipGroupRef.current
      .append("text")
      .style("font-size", `${toolTipFontSize}px`)
      .style("dominant-baseline", "hanging");

    tooltipTextValueRef.current = tooltipGroupRef.current
      .append("text")
      .style("font-size", `${toolTipFontSize}px`)
      .style("dominant-baseline", "hanging")
      .attr("dy", "1em");

    dotRef.current = svg
      .append("circle")
      .attr("r", 4)
      .style("fill", "steelblue")
      .style("opacity", 0);
  }, [data]);

  // syncrhonizing tooltips across the plots
  useEffect(() => {
    const x = xRef.current;
    const y = yRef.current;
    const showToolTip = () => {
      verticalLineRef.current.style("opacity", 0.3);
      tooltipGroupRef.current.style("opacity", 1);
      dotRef.current.style("opacity", 1);
    };
    const hideToolTip = () => {
      verticalLineRef.current.style("opacity", 0);
      tooltipGroupRef.current.style("opacity", 0);
      dotRef.current.style("opacity", 0);
    };

    const updateTooltip = (index) => {
      const activeData = data[index];

      verticalLineRef.current
        .attr("x1", x(activeData.time))
        .attr("x2", x(activeData.time))
        .attr("y1", marginTop)
        .attr("y2", height - marginBottom + marginTop);

      tooltipTextTimeRef.current.text(`${activeData.time} (s)`);
      tooltipTextValueRef.current.text(`${activeData.value} (${units})`);

      dotRef.current
        .attr("cx", x(activeData.time))
        .attr("cy", y(activeData.value));
    };

    const svg = d3.select(svgRef.current);

    svg
      .on("mouseover", () => {
        showToolTip();
      })
      .on("mouseleave", () => {
        hideToolTip();
        setActiveIndex(null);
      })
      .on("mousemove", (event) => {
        const bisect = d3.bisector((d) => d.time).center;
        const index = bisect(data, x.invert(d3.pointer(event)[0]));
        updateTooltip(index);
        setActiveIndex(index);
      });

    if (activeIndex !== null) {
      showToolTip();
      updateTooltip(activeIndex);
    } else {
      hideToolTip();
    }
  }, [data, activeIndex]);

  return (
    <div
      style={{
        padding: `4px`,
      }}
    >
      <svg ref={svgRef} />
    </div>
  );
};

LinePlot.defaultProps = {
  label: "",
  units: "",
  labelFontSize: 16,
  tickFontSize: 14,
  toolTipFontSize: 18,
  height: 400,
  precision: 3,
};

export default LinePlot;
```